# Remounting all react child components after root state change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a pretty large application and would like to get some insight on the best way to re-render the application based on a root component state change.

**Sample Architecture**

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
 <Route component={Layout}>
  <IndexRoute component={Page} />
  <Route path={page} component={Page}></Route>
  ...
 </Route>
 <Route component={Layout}>
  <IndexRoute component={Page} />
  <Route path={page} component={Page}></Route>
  ...
  </Route>
```

In my architecture after a successful login i'm storing the users data in my App component. Every user has a client key which is used as the identifier as to which clients database/data to display. The behavior i would like to accomplish would be to update my current page with the new clients data after the a client change.

Now i could pass my data down to my components as props from my App component but i think this would be inefficient because of two reasons.

1. I would have to get the data for all my routes before rendering my App component.
2. My data would become "stale" until i re-render my App component.

Because of these reason i decided to let each page fetch it's own data using the `componentWillMount` life cycle hook, and passing the data down as props to the pages child components. This works for me because i'm able to fetch fresh data for each page upon navigation.

What i'm currently experiencing is that after a client change my application re-renders but since my current page has already mounted it doesn't fetch the new client data. But everything works as expected if i navigate away from the current page and then back to the page.

One solution i have in mind is to pass the users data down to each page and use the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle hook and perform a comparison check in order to fetch new data. I would like to prevent that if at all possible since my application will have 40+ pages.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you have mentioned about

> pass the users data down to each page and use the
>   `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle hook and perform a comparison
>   check in order to fetch new data.

is perfectly fine. Few examples of such a pattern in the wild:

- Redux repository [real world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/RepoPage.js#L30)
- React Router core team recommends this method too as per issue [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982#issuecomment-172173634).

Comment: I know this pattern works but along with having to add the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle hook to every page i would have to manually map the App components state to both the page layout and the page.

which would require me to use something like this 
`{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {user: this.state.user})}`.

in my mind this starts to affect maintainability and could also mean that there might be a better way of doing things. As addressed by [this comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1857#issuecomment-181042069)